# How do i write a trigger in sql to make sure when inserting a company into the table, if the zipcodes are the same then city will be same also?

Tags: java, sql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I'm trying to implement a trigger in sql and one of the rules of the table is that if the two of the company's zip codes are the same, then their city must be the same. I want to use triggers before insert to check for this condition. Zip and city are the attributes of the company table. Thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI, in the United States at least, a postal code ([ZIP code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_Code)) can cross political lines such as city and county borders.

Comment: Is there a reason you've settled on a trigger to solve this problem? Seems like something that's easy and more maintainable to address in application code rather than relying on the DB.